# Simple Injector initialize for both MVC and Web API controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have a Web API controller that has some resources DI'd. Out of later necessity I have added an MVC controller, now I need same resources DI'd there as well. Here is my original configuration:

```
    [assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(CineplexSearch.App_Start.SimpleInjectorWebApiInitializer), "Initialize")]

namespace CineplexSearch.App_Start
{
    using System.Web.Http;
    using SimpleInjector;
    using SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi;

    public static class SimpleInjectorWebApiInitializer
    {
        /// <summary>Initialize the container and register it as Web API Dependency Resolver.</summary>
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            var container = new Container();
            container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebApiRequestLifestyle();

            InitializeContainer(container);

            container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

            container.Verify();

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
                new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        }

        private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
        {
            container.Register<ICachingManager, CachingManager>(Lifestyle.Transient);
            container.Register<IDataAccessLayer, DataAccessLayer>(Lifestyle.Transient);
        }
    }
}
```

Can I register DI for MVC Controller in the same place as well? Can I reuse the container?

**Update:** I must be close, but now I get an error in the Web API controller that I need a parameterless constructor; I tried adding it, but then nothing gets injected of course

```
public static class SimpleInjectorWebApiInitializer
{
    /// <summary>Initialize the container and register it as Web API Dependency Resolver.</summary>
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

        InitializeContainer(container);

        container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        container.Verify();

        //GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<ICachingManager, CachingManager>(Lifestyle.Transient);
        container.Register<IDataAccessLayer, DataAccessLayer>(Lifestyle.Transient);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Can I reuse the container?

Yes you can, and you should. Every app domain should typically have one container instance.

The [MVC integration documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mvcintegration.html) of the Simple Injector documentation explains that you should set the MVC `DependencyResolver` as follows:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
```

To make things easier however, your should register the `WebRequestLifestyle` as `DefaultScopedLifestyle`:

```
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
```

This will work for Web API as well, since you are solely running Web API from within IIS.

So you need to configure both the DependencyResolvers.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I almost have it working, can you please see my update?

Comment: @FailedUnitTest  you need *both* the dependency resolvers. So the Web API dependency resolver as well.

Comment: Just so I completely understand, we should use both `.RegisterMvcControllers()` and `RegisterWebApiControlers()` as well as _both_ `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container))` _and_ `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver(new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container))`?

Comment: @Dr.Zim: If you use both Web API and MVC: yes.

Comment: Thank you @Dr.Zim. By your comment, i understood  the whole answer.

Comment: An exception is thrown System.TypeLoadException: 'Derived method 'get_Length' in type 'SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.WebRequestLifestyle' from assembly 'SimpleInjector.Integration.Web, Version=2.7.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=984cb50dea722e99' cannot reduce access.'

Comment: Wow, still on v2? Please make sure all Simple Injector packages are of the same version.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add my two cents because after reading Steven's answer and the comments below it I still got some errors. Eventually this had to do with the order in which things are getting configured.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //set the default scoped lifestyle
    Container container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

    ...
    //do class registration here. I did it with Scoped lifestyle
    ...
    //Let the SimpleInjector.Intergration packages register the controllers.       
    container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    //This must be here because we first need to do above before registering the web api. See WebApiConfig code.
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    //don't set the resolver here, do it in WebApiConfig.Register()
    //DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container));
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
    container.Verify(SimpleInjector.VerificationOption.VerifyAndDiagnose);
}
```

WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        //set the webApi resolver here!
        config.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(DependencyInjectionCoreSetup._Container);
        //then the rest..
        var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: DependencyInjectionCoreSetup?

Answer (score 1):

Also be aware that the `WebRequestLifestyle()` is obsolete at the time .
You can use instead:

```
//...

container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.AsyncScopedLifestyle();

//...
```

Comment: WebRequestLifestyle(bool) is obsolete. WebRequestLifestyle() is not obsolete.

https://simpleinjector.org/ReferenceLibrary/html/T_SimpleInjector_Integration_Web_WebRequestLifestyle.htm

The recommendation is to use AsyncScopedLifestyle in applications that solely consist of a Web API (or other asynchronous technologies such as ASP.NET Core) and use WebRequestLifestyle for applications that contain a mixture of Web API and MVC.

https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html?highlight=asyncscopedlifestyle#async-scoped-lifestyle-vs-web-request-lifestyle